# Trying to insert a contact form's data into two tables in a database (PhpMyAdmin) but getting insertion failed

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert data into two tables on PhpMyAdmin into bitnami-wordpress, but it isn't working. I'm using a template as well. The template successfully inserts data, but mine isn't working. Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the template

```
<?php
if($_POST['Submit'])
{
 $wpdb;
 $membername=$_POST['membernametextbox'];
 $phone=$_POST['phonetextbox'];
 $email=$_POST['emailtextbox'];
 $date=$_POST['datetextbox'];
 $paymenttype=$_POST['paymenttypetextbox'];
 
 if ($wpdb->insert('newmembers', array('membername'=>$membername,'phone'=>$phone,'email'=>$email))==false)wp_die('Database is down try again later!');
 
 else
     /* get_var method returns a single value whereas get_results method returns an array */
     $membernumber=$wpdb->get_var("Select max(membernumber) from newmembers");
     
     $wpdb->insert('subscription',array('date'=>$date,'paymenttype'=>$paymenttype,'membernumber'=>$membernumber));
     
     echo '<br><br> Data inserted succesfully!';
}
get_footer();
?>
```

And here is my version. My table names are 'organization' and 'donor.'

```
<?php
if($_POST['Submit'])
{
 $wpdb;
 $donorname=$_POST['donornametextbox'];
 $paymenttype=$_POST['paymenttypetextbox'];
 $organizationtype=$_POST['organizationtypetextbox'];
 $organizationname=$_POST['organizationnametextbox'];
 $address1=$_POST['address1textbox'];
 
 if ($wpdb->insert('organization', array('organizationtype'=>$organizationtype,'organizationname'=>$organizationname,'address1'=>$address1))==false)wp_die('Database is down try again later!');
 
 else
     /* get_var method returns a single value whereas get_results method returns an array */
     $organizationid=$wpdb->get_var("Select max(organizationid) from organization");
     
     $wpdb->insert('donor',array('donorname'=>$donorname,'paymenttype'=>$paymenttype,'organizationid'=>$organizationid));
     
     echo '<br><br> Data inserted succesfully!';
}
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you are initializing the `$wpdb` object. In WordPress, you should use the global `$wpdb` object, but in your code, you are simply declaring it as a local variable without initializing it.

```php
<?php
if($_POST['Submit'])
{
 global $wpdb; // Add this line 

 $donorname=$_POST['donornametextbox'];
 $paymenttype=$_POST['paymenttypetextbox'];
 $organizationtype=$_POST['organizationtypetextbox'];
 $organizationname=$_POST['organizationnametextbox'];
 $address1=$_POST['address1textbox'];
 
 if ($wpdb->insert('organization', array('organizationtype'=>$organizationtype,'organizationname'=>$organizationname,'address1'=>$address1))==false)wp_die('Database is down try again later!');
 
 else
     /* get_var method returns a single value whereas get_results method returns an array */
     $organizationid=$wpdb->get_var("Select max(organizationid) from organization");
     
     $wpdb->insert('donor',array('donorname'=>$donorname,'paymenttype'=>$paymenttype,'organizationid'=>$organizationid));
     
     echo '<br><br> Data inserted succesfully!';
}
get_footer();
?>
```

You can enable debugging in WordPress by adding the following lines to your `wp-config.php` file:

```php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

Check log any errors to a `debug.log` file in the `wp-content` directory.